# is there a way to render a web page that has X-Frame-Options: deny in its header response with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I want to render a web page that has `X-Frame-Options: deny` in a React app. I think I can't use `<iframe>`, so I'm searching for way to render the page with something else. I cannot make changes on the server side of this page, so I can't remove the `X-Frame-Options: deny`. What are my options?

Comment: @ZF007 I think the question is already pretty clear - OP wants to render a webpage like in an iframe, but the iframe option is not possible due to the remote page headers. OP is asking for suggestions on how to circumvent these headers limitations. No need for an MCVE in my opinion

Comment: @NinoFiliu Sharp, thx. Comment should have been: As a non-expert on this specific topic I cannot fully check if it fits fully [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So please check and give  more information where needed by editing your own question. Also state what you tried in another direction. This might help solving your question faster. End of Triage Review > Q moved to > Requires editing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to `fetch` the page as html and use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). But even if it is not blocked by some other header the result will be buggy and will have limited functionality.

I think it is not possible without some browser extension or proxy server which modifies those headers.